# Two ListViews with single List

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview

I have two ListViews into my Activity. I want to display items from a single List into these ListViews. I want alternate items into them. I have a single custom ListAdapter.

ie.  LeftListView should contain List items 0,2,4,6,8......
     RightListView should have list items 1,3,5,7,9.......

Can this be achieved?

Here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ItemsAdapter.java

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>{

Context context; 
LayoutInflater inflater;
int layoutResourceId;
float imageWidth;

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Integer[] items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;

    float width = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    float margin = (int)convertDpToPixel(10f, (Activity)context);
    // two images, three margins of 10dips
    imageWidth = ((width - (3 * margin)) / 2);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    FrameLayout row = (FrameLayout) convertView;
    ItemHolder holder;
    Integer item = getItem(position);

    if (row == null) {
        holder = new ItemHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView itemImage = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.itemImage = itemImage;
    } else {
        holder = (ItemHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    row.setTag(holder);
    setImageBitmap(item, holder.itemImage);
    return row;
}

public static class ItemHolder
{
    ImageView itemImage;
}

// resize the image proportionately so it fits the entire space
private void setImageBitmap(Integer item, ImageView imageView){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), item);
    float i = ((float) imageWidth) / ((float) bitmap.getWidth());
    float imageHeight = i * (bitmap.getHeight());
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (int) imageHeight;
    params.width = (int) imageWidth;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setImageResource(item);
}

public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    return px;
}
```

}

Comment: yes, get the values in two different arraylist and using sam adapter set it to these listviews

Comment: post your adapter code..

Comment: @kalyan I have posted the adapter code

Comment: before passing this Integer[] items array divide it into two arrays and pass it to the Adapter constructor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your data is stored in an ArrayList now, create two ArrayLists (one for each list).

For each ArrayList, populate the values and pass them to your adapter.

```
for(int x : list)
{
if(x%2 == 0)
leftList.add(x);
else
rightList.add(x);
}
```

`list` : ArrayList containing complete data

`leftList, rightList` : ArrayLists containing specific data

Comment: I just have one list with items. I want to alternate the data within both these lists so that both List show alternate list items

Comment: As swayam said, creating two arraylist is better solution for this.

Comment: @silwar how do I create two arrayLists out of a single List?

Comment: @user3713706 : updated my answer with the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 ArrayList with different values in it. Like, if you have values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Then do like below:

```
for(int i=0;i<mainArray;i++){
            if(i%2==0){
                evenArray.add(mainArray.get(i));
            }else{
                oddArray.add(mainArray.get(i));
            }
        }
```

Using above code you will have two different arraylist, then use it.